# getting updated location from GcmListenerService onMessageReceived

Tags: android, push-notification, gps, geolocation, google-geolocation

Hi I am working on app that when it receives push notification should get it's location and call server where then based on that it gets to show notification or swallow it.

Problem that I am a experiencing is that location is getting cashed and then I don't get to notify my clients in time which is essential. I obviously cannot subscribe to `onLocationChanged` as I need to make decision on message right then.

I have read about it and one of suggestions was to initialize `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` which should reset cache which I don't think it does, however enabling google maps does indeed help to get updated coordinates so I would assume this is indeed issue with caching.

Currently code looks like this (please don't judge it's prototype only):

```
 private String getLocation() {
    // Get the location manager
    new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }
    };
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
            getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if (bestProvider != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return "-1.1329097,51.257538";
            }
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        try {
            return location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return "-1.1329097,51.257538";
        }
    }
    return "-1.1329097,51.257538";
}

 public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);
    sendNotification = true;
    callEmergency();
}

public boolean callEmergency(){

    StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");
    try{
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        URL url = new URL("http://www.ears.uk.com/User/CheckForEmergency?token="+token+"&coordinates="+getLocation());
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        //  connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //  connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            chaine.append(line);
        }
        if(chaine.toString().equals("True")){
            sendNotification("Emergency Vehicle Approaching");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return chaine.toString() == "True";
}
```

**Is there a more appropriate solution to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if nothing triggered a location change even like say opening google maps or something you will still have a location from when a location change was last recorded.

if you need to have the latest location possible you should check the time of the location with `getTime` if the time of that location is within your limits then you can just use that location. If that time is say 5 hours old you probably want to get a new point in which you would have to start a location listener and get the first valid location then then stop the listener. For that part your should start a service because who knows how long it will take to get that location

Comment: But isn't there a way just  to trigger getting current location without having to create listeners, or disable caching. I like idea with getTime but as I understand I would have to track time in local storage somehow + I don't really care about good practices and battery life for prototype.

Comment: If you use the Fused Location API you can get a one time location but that still requires you to start a location listener https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#constant-summary